# Google Friend Connect - Logged in user profile info

Tags: openid, opensocial, google-friend-connect

I am trying to implement Google Friend Connect. Is it possible to obtain the email address of the logged in user? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  Google doesn't let you have this information for the obvious reason that they don't want you to spam their users.  If you need it, you'll have to ask for it explicitly.

Stuff that should be available via GFC:

- opensocial.Person.Field.ID
- opensocial.Person.Field.NAME
- opensocial.Person.Field.NICKNAME
- opensocial.Person.Field.THUMBNAIL_URL
- opensocial.Person.Field.PROFILE_URL